# Importing Classes and Inheriting a Class

Tags: java, inheritance, import

This is just a small one but i just need more clarity on these two.

Comment: Seek clarity in search.  Summarize your findings, ***then*** ask a question..

Comment: Can you next time do some web searching before ask a question ? It's too easy to find an answer about your question by google .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By import you tell the compiler that my program is going to use imported classes so please make them available.

```
import java.util
```

By inheriting class you are going to use class properties and functions (which are being inherited) in child class.

```
class Maruti extends Car{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`import` allows you to use the imported class in the class you're currently writing.

Inheriting, or using the `extends` keyword allows you to implement the current class with the functionality of the class you are inheriting from.

For instance:

```
public class Animal
{
    public void walk()
    {
        System.out.println("i am walking");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
    public void meow()
    {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cat catAnimal = new Cat();
        cat.walk();
        cat.meow();
    }
}
```

So as you can see in the above example, because `Cat extends Animal` the `Cat` class can do everything the `Animal` class can.

Answer (score 0):

`import` lets you see the class so you can `inherit` (aka extend) it.

Answer (score 0):

Importing classes are simply allowing your class to have access to these classes without using their fully qualified names.

For example, if you have the following:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main{
//this class has ACCESS to the JFrame class, but it isn't a JFrame because it doesn't inherit (extend) from one
}
```

Your Main class would have access to the methods and variables in the class javax.swing.JFrame without having to call it with that full name, it allows you to simply use JFrame.

Inheriting a class is extending your own class to gain access to a classes methods and variables because your class "is a" inherited class.

Here is some code that doesn't "import" JFrame, it uses its fully qualified name to extend itself so that it has access to every method/variable inside the JFrame class (as long as the modifier is public or protected).

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//this class IS a JFrame, and is not importing one, it's instead using the fully qualified name to extend itself and make it a JFrame.
}
```